# Call a function in main form from a User Control inside a flowpanellayout C# windowsforms

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

can anyone answer my question in the title?

It goes like this

### //Main Form

```
public partial class Main : Form
{

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public void Load_Main_Function()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I'm called from the User Control inside flowpanellayout");
    }
}
```

---

### //FlowPanel Form

```
public partial class FlowPanel : UserControl
{

    public FlowPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Load_Sample_Forms()
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Item_User_Control Item = new Item_User_Control();

            Item.Name.Text = "Test Item " + i;
            Item.Price.Text = i;
            Item.button.Name = i; 

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Item);


        }
    }
}
```

---

### //Item_User_Control (Main form function called from here)

```
public partial class Item_User_Control : UserControl
{
    public Item_User_Control()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Here comes my problem..
        //The method I tried
        Main mainForm = new Main();
        mainForm.Load_Main_Function();
        //I was thinking that this Item_User_Control was cast inside the loop of Flowpanel Form   
        //that there must be a conflict somehow or this form can't be seen during the inialization
        //of Main Form and that's why the function in Main Form can't be called from             
        //Item_User_Control button event


    }
}
```

---

I'm making an POS using C# Windows Forms and I'm stuck in this problem :) 
The layout works it shows 5 Item_User_Control inside flowpanellayout, it's just when clicking the button, nothing happens

need help guys, thanks!!!

Comment: Try: `((Main)Application.OpenForms[0]).Load_Main_Function();`

Comment: @JQSOFT it worked! But I tried it from User Control to User Control it gave me an error "Cannot convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' to 'UserControl'

Comment: You should use events.Don't make Item_User_Control dependent on MainForm like that.

Comment: @Dbuggy it was called after an event from Item_User_Control

Comment: @JoshuaPales True, that is the system notifying that there is a certain mouse action  occurring on your usercontrol. What you want, afaik, is to notify the container (currently mainform) of the flow panel that one of it's items was pressed and take some action.Usually done using events.

Comment: @Dbuggy can you give me a sample based on my post?

Answer (score 0):

Basic information about the event system can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/event-pattern)

In your code you could do it something like:

### //Main Form

```
public partial class Main : Form
{

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FlowPanel.FlowItemClicked += FlowPanel_FlowItemClicked;
    }

    private void FlowPanel_FlowItemClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I'm called because A flow item in the flow panel was clicked."); 
    }
}
```

---

### //FlowPanel Form

```
public partial class FlowPanel : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler FlowItemClicked; // Event to notify any item getting clicked.

    public FlowPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void Load_Sample_Forms()
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Item_User_Control Item = new Item_User_Control();

            Item.Name.Text = "Test Item " + i;
            Item.Price.Text = i;
            Item.button.Name = i; 

            // Handle FlowItemClicked event from this item.
            item.ItemClicked += (o,e) => { FlowItemClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty;) };

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Item);
        }
    }
}
```

---

### //Item_User_Control (Main form function called from here)

```
public partial class Item_User_Control : UserControl
{

    public event EventHandler ItemClicked; // Event to notify the item getting clicked.

    public Item_User_Control()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // When the button gets clicked, raise the ItemClicked event.
        ItemClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

---

Comment: This part gave me an error item.ItemClicked += () => { FlowItemClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty;) };

')' expected
invalid expression term ')'
; expected

Comment: Also tried Item.ItemClicked += () => { FlowItemClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); };  

gave me an error Delegate 'System.Eventhandler' does not take 0 arguments

Comment: ai.. my mistake. i didn't run the dang thing.. use `(o,e) => {...}`. needed because an event handler has two arguments.. the sender and the event arguments.

Comment: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

It runs but after clicking the button it gave me this error @Dbuggy

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? At which line does the error occur?

Comment: Yes in this line `Item.ItemClicked += (o, e) => { FlowItemClicked.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty); };`

Comment: Seems that the FlowItemClicked was not setup as expected. That should have been done in the Main form's constructor. Check if you use the corrent name for FlowPanel because i don't know which name it has on your form.

Comment: I'm trying to call a function in **FlowPanelForm** it goes like this: `when an order is placed in the form, the orders list would refresh`

Comment: This sounds like a totally different kind of question from your original one. Which imho deserves a new question on SO.

Comment: It's similar hehe okay back to the real one... when I tried your code, it gave me an error, all variables are the same

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make an instance of your Main Form "Globally Accessible":

// On Main Form

```
public partial class Main : Form
{
    public static Main Instance { get; private set; }

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Instance = this; // Initiate an instance of your form
    }

    public void Load_Main_Function()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("I'm called from the User Control inside flowpanellayout");
    }
}
```

// On FlowPanel - your custom control. Remember to call your Load_Sample_Forms() method.

```
public partial class FlowPanel : UserControl
{
    public FlowPanel()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load_Sample_Forms();
    }

    public void Load_Sample_Forms()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Item_User_Control Item = new Item_User_Control();

            Item.Name = "Test Item " + i;
            Item.Price.Text = i.ToString();
            Item.button.Name = i.ToString();

            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(Item);
        }
    }
}
```

// On Item_User_Control

```
public partial class Item_User_Control : UserControl
{
    public Item_User_Control()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Main.Instance.Load_Main_Function(); // Execute any main function regardless of signature;
    }
}
```

Comment: You do have an instance of your custom FlowPanel control ON Mainform? and a button ON Item_User_Control, whose button_Click event is set to that IN Item_User_Control? Remember to initiate your FlowPanel Control on mainform

Comment: I already had, when I tried debugging it, it runs the code but the function did not loaded

Comment: What I've noticed is that you have this nifty little function called Load_Sample_Forms(); but you never actually invoke it; You need to put this e.g. after your InitializeComponent; or invoke it externally somewhere else. Updated my example accordingly. You've also made sure that you dragged an instance of your custom FlowControl onto your form - and NOT the out-of-the-box one from the toolbox, correct? Yours should be a *cs file somewhere in the Solution explorer

Comment: Also make sure that your button and Price controls are indeed made public; you might have to look at the bottom of your designer - generated code and "cut" the controls from there. Make sure that you assign the button to your event; e.g.             this.button.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button_Click);